# WORKGROUP\user: No Mapping between account names and Security Id was done,

Tags: postgresql, chocolatey, beaker, serverspec, windows-server-2022

I installed PostgreSQL using Chocolaty and Beaker tests in Windows Server, but I got this error

**WORKGROUP\user: No Mapping between account names and Security Id was done.**

Then:

**Initdb: Error: could not access directory ¯d: /postgres/data®: Permission denied**

I though the problem because of WORKGROUP, I have tried most of solutions mentioned in Google search but unfortunately with no success.

Comment: Does this actually have anything at all to do with Puppet?  If the question were about how to write Puppet manifests to manage the installation then perhaps it could be brought on topic by addition of a [mre].

Comment: You have right, it does not have anything with puppet, i already edited the tags. The Beaker tests is written used serverspec

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows 11 username must have characters that the PostgreSQL installer doesn't like, as it did for me with my French accent on `Sébastien`.
So there's no need to create a new Windows account or do crazy manipulations in the Windows registry, just change your username in the `netplwiz`, which you'll start from a command line/terminal in Administrator mode, choose the 'problematic user' in the User Accounts window and go to 'Properties'. All you have to do is give a more English name and restart the PC. The PostgreSQL installation now works.